# Cant install Ubuntu 12.04, select CD-ROM Boot type

Tags: 12.04, boot, cd

I'm having trouble installing Ubuntu 12.04 from boot disk on a friends computer. when starting the computer with boot disk the message appears:

> 1.
>
> 2.
>
> Select CD-ROM Boot Type:

If I enter 1 it goes to starting windows screen and boots 7 as normal

If I enter 2 it goes to a screen with a blinking dash in the top left corner for a minute or two then goes to the starting windows screen and loads 7 as normal

Comment: Discussed here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1652695 *although not fully resolved (IMHO).*

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like either the disk was not burned properly or the computer does not fully support booting from dvd in that way; you might try reburning or creating a usb based boot device.